# $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{(a^4+(bx)^2} - \sqrt{a^4+b}}{x}$

Tags: limits, analysis, functions

calculate...
this is my homework

the photo is my solution proposal but I don't know what to do next....[image]

Comment: Are you sure you copied the problem correctly? As you wrote it in the question it's not "indeterminate"; the nummerator has a non-zero limit. Seems like $\lim(\sqrt{a^4+(bx)^2}-\sqrt{a^4})/x$ would be a better question

Comment: Please, no picture. Typeset your solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{a^4+b^2x^2}-\sqrt{a^4+b}\rightarrow a^2-\sqrt{a^4+b}.$$
If $b\neq0$ then the limit does not exist.

If $b=0$ then the limit is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Write your term in the form
$$\frac{x^2\left(b^2-\frac{b}{x^2}\right)}{\pm x\left(\sqrt{\frac{a^4}{x^2}+b^2}+\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{x^2}+\frac{b}{x^2}}\right)}$$